# Router.use() requires middleware function but got a String

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Full error:

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string
    at Function.use (/Users/choragore/Desktop/todolist-v1/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/choragore/Desktop/todolist-v1/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (/Users/choragore/Desktop/todolist-v1/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/choragore/Desktop/todolist-v1/app.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
```

I have tried other solutions, such as the const `router = express.Router();` and `module.exports = router;` solution that worked for others, but not for me. Whenever I try to run the code using nodemon, it just comes up with the above error. All the modules installed are body parser, express and ejs. The package.json has the correct dependencies. I don't know where I have gone wrong.

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

app.use('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    var today = new Date();
    var currentDay = today.getDay();
    var day = "";

    switch (currentDay) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        break;

    default:
    console.log("Error: current day is equal to " + currentDay);

    }

    res.render("list", {
    kindofDay: day
    });

});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: why do you import the router? You never use it and you dont need to export an module (you cannot do in index files)

Comment: why you are having a router, can you delete line number 3 and at bottom export app instead of router.

Comment: where you have app.use('whatever' , //here you need to add a router, not a string);
Something like in index.js const whateverRouter = require('./routes/whatever);
and then: app.use('/whatever', whateverRouter);

Comment: @Raghuveer Can you give the example; the same error came up

Comment: @Pandamora, just looked closely in your code, you have typed app.use('view engine', 'ejs'), it should be app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

Answer (score 0):

```
    const express = require("express");
    const router = express.Router();
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    var app = express();

    app.use('view engine', 'ejs');

    router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    
        var today = new Date();
        var currentDay = today.getDay();
        var day = "";

        switch (currentDay) {
            case 0:
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
               day = "Monday";
              break;
          case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
        break;

    default:
    console.log("Error: current day is equal to " + currentDay);

    }

    res.render("list", {
    kindofDay: day
    });

});

router.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the file in express app

Here is an example [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/express-get-day-wercu) of how it works. Hope It can helps!